# How can I select random value that previously selected value are excluded from the selection

Tags: matlab

I want to select a random value but previously selected value are excluded from the selection. How can make like this??

[image]

Comment: Are these random numbers between a certain minimum and maximum?

Comment: @David No. consider only above picture. Number is 1 to 16 like picture, if i select 10, next step can't select "10". :)

Comment: So they are random numbers between 1 and 16 with no repetition.

Comment: ... which is exactly what [`randsample`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is generalized one.. `A` could have any values, some numbers repeating or non repeating.. also any number of(of course upto `numel(A)`) could be generated.

**Code:**

```
A = randi(50,3,3);                   %// replace this with your own matrix
idx = 1:numel(A);                    %// generating linear indices
noOfRandNos = 5;                     %// How many such numbers do you want?
randNos(noOfRandNos,1) = 0;          %// pre Allocation

%// This loop is run as many times as the number of such numbers you require.
%// Maximum possible runs will be equal to the numel(A).
for ii = 1:noOfRandNos       
    randidx = randi(numel(idx));    %// generating a rand Indx within the current size of idx
    randNos(ii) = A(idx(randidx));  %// Getting corresponding number in-turn from the indx
    idx(randidx) = [];              %// removing the particular indx so that it is not repeated
end
```

**Sample Run:**

```
>> A

A =

12    28    25
23    27    32
49    12    34

>> randNos

randNos =

28
49
34
12
32
```

Comment: I think `A=A(:);A=A(randperm(numel(A)));A(1:noOfRandNos)` can replace your loop

Answer (score 3):

Create a list of random numbers within the range, and pick one at a time

```
minimum=1;
maximum=16;
randomNumbers=randperm(maximum-minimum+1)+minimum-1
```

and sample output is `randomNumbers=[7 13 2 15 12 4 16 11 9 5 3 1 14 6 8 10]`. You can display each number sequentially using, for example,

```
for k=1:maximum+1-minimum
    randomNumbers(k)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To pick `5` numbers from the set `1:16` without repetition: use [`randsample`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html):

```
result = randsample(1:16, 5);
```

Comment: This would be my preference. The only downside (beyond a small amount of extra overhead – it's based on `randi` and `randperm` under the hood) is that it's a toolbox function, though nearly everyone has the Stats toolbox.